# changing output from column to rows in python to csv

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to output a few separate variables (separate data sets created previously in my code) as a single csv file. I have found the most luck using np.asarray and np.savetxt. I am now trying to format the csv output file and want to have my variables read in each column (header then data below for each variable being written to csv). I have successfully had the data transfer to the csv file along with adding column title headers, but I cannot get the variables to format from one row into separate rows.

I have tried changing the order from 'C' to 'F' in np.asarray. I have also used a few things with the csv writing library in python but I did find np.savetxt and asarray were the best routes (so far)

my code for this is as follows. Each variable type in csvData is listed as 'float64' in my variable explorer if that helps at all.

```
csvData=np.asarray([[timestep], [IQR_bot],[IQR_top],[median], 
[prcnt95],[prcnt5], [KFTG_tot]], dtype=object, order='C')

np.savetxt("pathout.csv",csvData,fmt='%s', header='Timestep, 
IQR_bot,IQR_top,median,prcnt95,prcnt5, KFTG_top')
```

I want each input variable from csvData to be its own separate column of data tied with the respective header listed in np.savetxt. This code is not currently throwing any error messages, but the output format is not what I want it to be.

Comment: What's the `shape` of `csvData`?  Have tried `csvData.transpose()`?  If everything is `float` you drop the `dtype=object` and use a float format in `savetxt`.

Comment: the shape of csvData is (7,1). I've tried using transpose but it wasn't working before. Would that be after the header part of savetxt? Also, are you saying to delete the dtype from csvData?

Comment: Have you looked at the array?

Comment: You aren't giving us enough information.  We are left guessing as to what is wrong, and what you want.  What's in these data sets?  are they all the same size?

Comment: `savetxt` takes a 2d array, iterates on the first dimension (rows), formats the row (using the `fmt`) and writes that to a file.  Try something simple, e.g. `np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)` to get a feel for that; try different `fmt`.  If you want 7 columns, you need an array that is (n,7) shape.  `object` dtype and `%s` handles almost anything, but doesn't give you much control over the layout (column size, precision, etc).